# Book about a talking robot that broke down?

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship

I remember having read a book about a robot that was in charge of a space ship, while the human commander was in some sort of sleeping state. The robot broke down and was mostly talking gibberish. I think it got fixed by a civilization that the ship stumbled upon.

I read the book around 2010, but I know for a fact that it was written before the 2000s(it was an old book that my father had in his childhood). I'm also pretty sure that the book had an almost monochrome cover. I very rarely remember the author's name of most of the books that I read, but I'm quite positive it wasn't Asimov or Cliford D. Simak(I read books by the both of them in that period and would most likely remember if any of them was the author).

The book itself was translated and I have no idea in what language was it originally written. I think the title had Odyssey or a similar word in it, but couldn't find anything after searching online.

I'll update the post if I remember anything else.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is quite terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum, I added some extra details. Thank you for the link! I'll keep on reading on there and edit my post if I realize I forgot something.

Comment: @user14111, the book was definitely about a space ship. I edited my post making this change and added some extra details. Thanks!

Comment: If it was an old book your father had in his childhood, I guess it's from *way* before the 2000s. How much can you narrow down the search space? Before 1960? Was the translation you read in English?

Comment: Well, he was born in 1966, so I would say he had it somewhere between 1970-1980. The translation was in Romanian.

Comment: Could it have been Arthur C Clarke's "2001: a Space Odyssey"? That features a spacecraft, hibernation, and a malfunctioning computer which starts talking gibberish when it is being disabled. At the end the ship encounters another civilisation, but they don't fix the computer.